# Minimize the maximum absolute difference of adjacent elements when at most k elements can changed to any integer

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

We have given an array of integers `A` with `n` elements, and an integer `k`.

We need to minimize the maximum absolute difference between the adjacent elements, such that at most `k` elements can be changed to any integer.

With constraints: `n <= 2000` and `-10^9 <= A[i] <= 10^9` for all `0 <= i < n`. Also, `k <= n`.

My approach was to try binary search. I kept lower limit as zero and upper limit as maximum absolute difference of adjacent elements currently in the array.
Then check if it is possible to make an array having some amount, let's say `m = (l + (r - l) / 2)`, is possible after changing k elements to have as the maximum absolute difference of adjacent elements.

But I was not able to check this possibility efficiently? I tried to brute force my way by changing the adjacent elements if the difference is greater than said `m`. But I am missing something here.
Can anyone suggest any solutions?

Comment: “But I was not able to check this possibility” Why?

Comment: Actually what I meant was that brute force solution did not work and I am not able to think of any other efficient solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hint: Within the binary search, you can use dynamic programming to check whether an absolute difference of `m` is achievable in `k` changes. For each array prefix `A[0..i]` and value `v`, write a dynamic programming formula for '# of changes needed for `A[0..i]` to have absolute difference at most `m`, given that `A[0..i]` will end with `A[i]=v`'.

Comment: @kcsquared: You say "given that `A[0..i]` will end with `A[i]=v`". This is not given. Take `A=[28,42,37,...]`, `m=10`. With `i=0`, zero changes required. With `i=1`, `A[0..1]` contains a difference of `14`. We may set `A[0]=42` or `A[1]=32..52`. We don't have one given `A[1]` for the next iteration. Even worse, we might change both `A[0]` and `A[1]` (e.g.`A=[28,42,37,1000,1000,1000,1000]`). I think dynamic programming doesn't solve this.

Comment: @Jojonete I'm not sure I understand your partial example, for instance, 'We may set `A[0]=42` or `A[1]=32..52`' should probably be 'We may set `A[0]=42` or `A[1]=18..38`'. Also, I probably didn't explain the idea very well or in enough detail. "Dynamic programming" might be a misleading term for it, since there would technically be infinitely many subproblems. I'll post an answer with the algorithm to clear things up.

Comment: It seems that I can't edit my comment now, but you're right, that `32..52` should be `18..38`. And yes, I meant that, when you say that `A[0..i]` ends with `A[i]=v`, that `v` can be quite anything at all (I guess this is what you call "technically infinitely many subproblems"), so I don't see the point of saying that `A[i]=v` is "given". Anyhow, I agree comments are too short for all the details (I myself had to cut down my own explanation), so posting an answer with all the details sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is possible to solve using [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach.

We will reduce full task to sub-tasks recursively. For each position `i` within array if we're allowed to modify `k0` elements lets build an array `d[i][k0]` that says what is the answer for sub-task of array `A[0..i]` and custom `k0` values to change. With one exception - `d[i][k0]` gives optimal solution for the case if `A[i]` is not being changed.

Now if we can build an answer for `d[i][k0]` if we know all answers for smaller `i`. Remember that by definition `A[i]` is not changed. It means we can build a segment of changed values `A[l+1..i-1]` (here `segment_len = i - l - 1`) plus use answer `d[l][k0 - segment_len]`, out of these two we can see that `d[i][k0]` is maximum of `d[l][k0 - segment_len]` and minimized difference inside changed segment. We can see that segment can be built optimally just by taking step equal to `(last - first + segment_len - 1) / segment_len`.

Now iterating over all lengths of a segments we can find minimal possible `d[i][k0]`. Final answer for whole task is `d[n][k]`.

I think better optimization is possible, but I solved this Dynamic Programming task through 3 nested loops. If I give random input to my code, it returns answer after exactly 1 second for `n = 1000, k = 500` and after 8 seconds for `n = 2000, k = 1000`.

I even have ideas how to speedup this considerably. But probably I'll implement them later if I have time.

So time complexity of my algorithm is `O(n * k^2)` of simple operations and memory complexity is `O(n * k)`.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/3xhGq3TEj)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

using i32 = int32_t;

i32 Solve(std::vector<i32> const & A, i32 n, i32 k) {
    std::vector<std::vector<i32>> d(n + 1, std::vector<i32>(k + 1));
    for (i32 i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
        for (i32 k0 = 0; k0 <= k; ++k0) {
            i32 rmin = std::numeric_limits<i32>::max();
            for (i32 j = 0; j <= k0; ++j) {
                i32 r = 0;
                if (i - 1 - j < 0)
                    r = 0;
                else if (i >= n)
                    r = d[i - 1 - j][k0 - j];
                else {
                    i32 step = (std::abs(A[i] - A[i - 1 - j]) + j) / (j + 1),
                        prev = d[i - 1 - j][k0 - j];
                    r = std::max(step, prev);
                }
                rmin = std::min(rmin, r);
            }
            d[i][k0] = rmin;
        }
    return d[n][k];
}

#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

void Test() {
    auto Time = []{
        static auto const gtb = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - gtb).count();
    };

    std::mt19937_64 rng{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<i32> distr(-1'000'000'000, 1'000'000'000);
    i32 n = 1'000, k = 500;
    std::vector<i32> A(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i)
        A[i] = distr(rng);
    //for (auto x: A) std::cout << x << " "; std::cout << std::endl;
    auto tim = Time();
    i32 res = Solve(A, n, k);
    tim = Time() - tim;
    std::cout << "Result " << res << ", time " << std::fixed
        << std::setprecision(4) << tim << " sec" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Test();
}
```

Output:

```
Result 295187479, time 1.0335 sec
```